# How does "HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress" work? Which IP does it get?

Tags: c#, proxy, ip

I want to get ip address from the user client in c#,and i was suggested to use:

```
var userAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

I am curious about how it works - which IP does it get? If the client uses a proxy-server, do I get the IP of the proxy-server instead of the real IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply the IP address that the server sees the request has originated from.

So, in the case of a proxy that is used to make the request, yes, you will get the proxy server IP.

Comment: ,thank you for your replay! if the proxy-server uses a proxy-server too, does it choose the closest request?